# PHP: call dynamic function, but in a class?

Tags: php, oop, class

I am trying to create an initialisation function that will call multiple functions in the class, a quick example of the end result is this:

```
$foo = new bar;
$foo->call('funca, do_taxes, initb');
```

This will work fine normally with call_user_func function, but what I really want to do is do that inside the class, I haven't a clue how to do this, a quick example of my unworking code is as follows:

```
class bar {
   public function call($funcs) {
       $funcarray = explode(', ', $funcs);
       foreach($funcarray as $func) {
          call_user_func("$this->$func"); //???
       }
   }
   private function do_taxes() {
       //...
   }
}
```

How would I call a dynamic class function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a lot simpler than you think, since PHP allows things like [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (and also variable object member names):

```
foreach($funcarray as $func) {
    $this->$func();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amber, I am glad I could connect to two and finish my script now.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use an array, like [Example #4 in the manual](http://us.php.net/call_user_func):

```
call_user_func(array($this, $func));
```

Comment: +1. I tend to prefer `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()` over `$this->$func()`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

```
$this->$func();
```

EDIT - disregard last post, i was a little hasty and misunderstood

You can do something similar in place of `call_user_func` either for native or user functions

```
function arf($a) {print("arf $a arf");}

$x = 'strlen';
$f2 = 'arf';

print($x('four')."\n");
$f2($arg1);
```

OUT

```
4
arf  arf
```

Answer (score 0):

when we want to check whether a class function/method exists within the class,

then this could help

inside class...

```
 $class_func = "foo";

 if(method_exists($this , $class_func ) ){
    $this->$class_func();
  }

 public function foo(){
   echo " i am called ";
 }
```